# prevent child div to overflow parent div css/tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a div that has a child div. This child div has a couple of input fields nested in a html table (for now). My problem is the input fields on the child div are overflowing the parent container div.

My aim is to have the child div and therefore the content never overflow the parent div without adding a scrollbar.
I've tried multiple 'overflow-xx' attributes but that just hides the content and adds a scroll bar.

Heres my code:

```
<div class="p-10 w-5/12 text-center">
  <div class="border-2 border-solid border-indigo-300 p-3 rounded shadow-2xl">
    <h2>Spielfeld 1</h2>
    <div class="h-96 border border-solid border-indigo-300 rounded flex">
      <div class="w-full">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Runter</th>
            <th>Frei</th>
            <th>Hoch</th>
            <th>Neiba</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" id="" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" id="" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" id="" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" id="" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by adding some CSS to your `table` and `input` controls.

Apply `width: 100%` to both the tale and input controls. Then you can use `table-layout: fixed` and `box-sizing: border-box` to size the controls and table inside the container.

```css
/* ignore .w-full css - it's used to set the width for this demo */
.w-full {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td input {      
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-10 w-5/12 text-center">
  <div class="border-2 border-solid border-indigo-300 p-3 rounded shadow-2xl">
    <h2>Spielfeld 1</h2>
    <div class="h-96 border border-solid border-indigo-300 rounded flex">
      <div class="w-full">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Runter</th>
            <th>Frei</th>
            <th>Hoch</th>
            <th>Neiba</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" id="" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" id="" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" id="" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" id="" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```